# How do I eliminate load flicker loading <head> from file (preferably synchronously)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Server side `include`s don't work here since it's not traditionally "served".

I'm trying to import the head content from a shared file to reduce shared code (I'm doing this with other shared elements across all pages just fine), but because it includes the styles, it's causing a flicker in the form of unstyled elements.

I'm using jQuery at present to load the content asynchronously (which isn't optimal, but I haven't found a synchronous solution that actually works), but I'm more than open to a vanilla JS solution so there's not the overhead of having to load jQuery first (to reduce the delay despite it being locally hosted).

Here is the existing code:

plan.html:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function(){ $("head").load("head.html") }); </script>
</head>
```

head.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!--Styles/Fonts-->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="styles/marketing-plan-normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/marketing-plan-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--IE Compatibility - Modernizr-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/modernizr.js"></script>

<!-- Adding the favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/js-logo-small.png"/>

<title>Sales and Marketing Planner</title>
```

Comment: It's odd to load html in this way, but if you must, load flicker can be prevented with an initially set loader image/gif to be displayed when the page first launches. This should be created in Markdown/CSS, otherwise you're just perpetuating the issue. The second parameter of the `.load` method takes a function as a callback for when the load completes. In that callback simply remove the loader from the page. ** also I believe what you mean is _asynchronous_ :)

Comment: @zfrisch Yeah, I just read that `load` and `get` are asynchronous...I'm wanting to get the head data synchronously so that it puts off building the rest of the content until it has all styling available. Edited to reflect this in the ask.

Comment: You can't delay building the rest of the page (unless you load it from somewhere else after loading the `head`...don't do this) but you can hide it until the head is loaded.  Put the whole body in a wrapper div (or whatever) and hide it using CSS until the head is fully loaded.

Comment: Wrapping everything else in a div and keeping it `hidden` or `visibility:none` didn't work, either. I've reverted in the project but I would still love to know what a working solution is here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.write()`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<link href="/use/abs/path/here/styles/marketing-plan-normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
</script>
</head>
```

It fails to work with `<base>` element in some browsers, so better use absolute urls.

In Chrome it triggers a console warning referring to https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write even if there's no script insertion. This situation may change in the future.

EDIT: Oops, I haven't paid enough attention to your case. I'm afraid it's not possible without combining document.write and sync AJAX. Please don't do that.